# Programatic access to call stack in .net

Tags: .net, reflection, callstack

How can I get programmatic access to the call stack?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `StackTrace` and `StrackFrame` classes in `System.Diagnostics`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use the `StackTrace` and `StackFrame` classes. Throwing an exception just to get the stack trace is completely misusing exceptions.