# Is it possible to get the name method of that calls another method?

Tags: vb.net, methods

This is what I am talking about:

```
Public Shared Sub Test1()
    Test2()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Test2()
    MsgBox(Test2.LastMethod) ' Test1
End Sub
```

I would imagine if this is possible, `System.Reflection` will be utilized?

Any thoughts?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434/programatic-access-to-call-stack-in-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatic access to call stack in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434/programatic-access-to-call-stack-in-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the  System.Diagnostics.StackFrame class.

```
 StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
 MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
 Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
```

As a side note you shouldn't depend on who you caller is and shouldn't use this unless you are writing a debugger or for logging purposes.

Comment: Another caveat: if the method is JIT-inlined it will return the wrong method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim stackFrame As New Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)
stackFrame.GetMethod.Name.toString() & stackFrame.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName.tostring()
```

Should give you the full name.

Answer (score 0):

This question should help:
[Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Be careful how you do this.  If your method is JIT-inlined you might see the wrong method.