# How to known the stack level reached in .NET?

Tags: .net, debugging, stack

How to know and then **print** out (in debug) the **stack level** reached in a certain moment inside a function call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434/programatic-access-to-call-stack-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().FrameCount
```